# Make a custom Excel data entry form appear based upon a cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping to have a UserForm that automatically appears based upon a range of cells. If a cell within the range equals 'yes' I want it to trigger the UserForm to appear. Any code examples that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By "data entry form", do you mean UserForm?

If not, read no further. I'm on the wrong track and apologies in advance.

Otherwise, assuming your UserForm has the default name UserForm1 (change the name if/where applicable), and then you want it to appear if the value of Cell A1 = 1, then you could use something like this,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address <> "$A$1" Then Exit Sub
        If .Value = 1 Then
            UserForm1.Show vbModeless
        Else
            UserForm1.Hide
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Some things worth mentioning,

1. The above code is Event code. There are various kinds of Event code. In this case, it should go into the relavent Sheet module (for example, Sheet1).
2. As you might guess, `UserForm1.Hide` will hide the UserForm, but not close it. You might be better off to use `Unload UserForm1`, which will close it, and you will probably need to do that sooner or later, but at this time, it's unclear what you are after. Not your fault of course, I understand that you are just asking for some generic code to get started.

Added for new request,

````
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim blnRangeIntersectExists As Boolean
    Dim blnAnswerExists As Boolean
    Dim rngCell As Range
        
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$A$22")) Is Nothing Then blnRangeIntersectExists = True
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$1:$G$22")) Is Nothing Then blnRangeIntersectExists = True
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$J$1:$J$22")) Is Nothing Then blnRangeIntersectExists = True
    
    If blnRangeIntersectExists = False Then Exit Sub
            
    For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
    
        If rngCell.Value = 1 Then blnAnswerExists = True
    
    Next rngCell
           
    If blnAnswerExists = True Then

        UserForm1.Show vbModeless

    Else

        UserForm1.Hide

    End If
    
End Sub```
````

Comment: Yes, UserForm is what I meant.  I edited my original post to reflect the update.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Code provided only works and populates the UserForm for the specific referenced cell, A1.  What if I wanted the code to work across a range of cells (i.e. A1:A22 and G1:G22 and J1:J22).  If any of the cells within those ranges = 1 than the UserForm appears. Would it still be using `.Address` or will it be a `Range` code in place of `.Address`?

Comment: Not perfect, but look at the new code.